# Android location tradeoff between accuracy and battery consumption

Tags: android, gps, location, wifi, battery

Is there any model to determine the battery drainage in android due to gps? I am actually trying to find an optimum tradeoff between accuracy and battery consumption due to gps and mobile networks for location access.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to determine the drainage, I can only pride a method for changing the power consumption and accuracy, hope this helps a little.

```
public static void changeProviderCriteria(boolean fineAccuracy, String power){
    Criteria crit = new Criteria();

    if(fineAccuracy){
        crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    }else{
        crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
    }

    if(power.equalsIgnoreCase("high")){
        crit.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
    }else if(power.equalsIgnoreCase("medium")){
        crit.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM);
    }else if(power.equalsIgnoreCase("low")){
        crit.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    }
    String provider="";
    if(locationManager==null){

    }else{
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(crit, true);
    }

    if(provider==null){

    }else{
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, currentRefreshTime, currentRefreshDist, locationListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if I set fineAccuracy as true and my power is medium or low, then will it use my gps or cellular network?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. I just use COARSE and MEDIUM when the device is on route to somewhere, and FINE + HIGH when at the destination.

Answer (score 1):

The [Location and Battery Drain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81W61JA6YHw&index=7&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE) video from [Android Performance Patterns](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE) might shed some more info on your problem.

The basic issue comes down to finding a balance between Location Resolution, and Location Update Frequency.

If you mark "setInterval" at too high of a rate, then you'll be constantly banging on the GPS chip to grab location, and thus wasting battery for each ping. Even worse, is still getting pings when you don't need them (like when the app is in the background) Setting it too-low, of course then doesn't update your app fast enough. The ideal scenario is to adjust the interval based upon need, and only use what you need.

On the resolution side, it's all about using the minimum resolution for your need. NetworkLocation uses less battery than fine-GPS location, and so switching between the two on-demand can help save battery and still provide usefulness to the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot Colt for the Videos. The videos have helped me get insight.